# Upload a temporary image on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, image, file, temporary-files

I want to simply upload an image so I have a path that links to it temporarily (not the user's local route), that way I will send that path to the backend and there it will be saved on a database. Since it is only for a few seconds until the backend saves it permanently, I want it to be deleted afterwards.

I've been trying with fileReader but so far I have no clue on how to achieve this.

Comment: here we go, If you are getting the image using input file. then just get the file and save it using angular file save to a temp directory then upload it. when the server done remove the temp one. that's it.

Comment: @A.Hussien Can you attach an example? It's being more difficult than expected, specially since I'm getting this error `Error: saveAs is not supported. Please include saveAs polyfill`